# Discord.py + Bottlepy

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py, bottle

I wanted to run a Bottlepy script with a Discord.py script, but only the Bottlepy script is started.

This is my source:

```py
import asyncio
import bottle
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=[">", "<", ".", "?", "!"])

#here where my script (not spectacular)

client.run("xxxxxXXXXxxXXetXxXXfXXxXXxXXXXxXxxxXxXX")
bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottle will never run because client.run is  blocking. So you need to run bottle in a different thread.

Consider this

```
bot.run(TOKEN)
print("foobar") # this line will not run until the bot process ends.
```

So, one of this processes needs to un in an alternate thread

Answer (score 1):

[`Client.start`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.start) is a coroutine. You'll want to use an event loop to run it.

Answer (score 0):

To run a Discord bot, use

```
client.run('token')
```

(if you want to read up on what client.start() does: [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.start))

Now what will happen, is that only your discord bot will run and the bottle script will never be called. To run both of them in parallel, I reccomend looking into [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Comment: i know that i run a discord.py bot with client.run("token")
But bottlepy is synchronous and discordpy asynchronous.
i dont know how i can use threading.

Comment: discord.py's events and functions are asynchronous but client.run() is still a blocking operation and nothing after it will be executed. I've provided you a link to the python documentation about threading, I really reccomend you read up over there.

Comment: The Discord bot can simply be run asynchronously without using `Client.run`. However, if what you do afterwards is [blocking](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean), then your Discord bot will not function properly, and you *will* want to run it in a separate thread.